# zend framework deployment in server

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, deployment

I have a server, where I have uploaded my work in zend framework(in a subdomain). the folder name is 'visit'.

So, When I go to: http://mysitename.com/visit, it shows a directory structure:

```
Parent Directory
application/
docs/
library/
nbproject/
public/
tests/
```

But when I go to: http://mysitename.com/visit/public, i get the index page of my project.

But I want to get my index page , when I type:    http://mysitename.com/visit

can you please give me the correct htaccess it need?

Answer (score 3):

Also, these other approaches to deploying in shared hosting can help:

- [Zend Framework on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115547/zend-framework-on-shared-hosting)
- http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html
- http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/
- http://www.ttech.it/en/article/2010/03/zend-framework-all-projects-files-on-document-root/

In particular, an [answer by tharkun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115547/zend-framework-on-shared-hosting/1115685#1115685) led me to write it up in more detail in a [blog post](http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following rule set, which is in part a partially modified version of the [one described in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/project-structure.rewrite.html).

.htaccess file in /visit:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Guard against people visiting /public/ directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]\s/visit/public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /visit/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# Make sure we've rewritten to the ./public/ directory already
RewriteCond $0 ^public/
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The index file is now at /visit/public/index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ /visit/public/index.php [NC,L]
```