# Zend framework deployment

Tags: zend-framework

Hello
I wanted to upload my web project done with zend framework on my ftp server.
I have uploaded it to the public_html/projects/myproject directory (I uploaded whole folder structure, directories: application, docs, library, Obsolete, public, scripts, tests, Zend).
Now if I type www.mydomain.com/projects/myproject I see all these folders.
If I want to run project I have to type  www.mydomain.com/projects/myproject/public

I am not really surprised with that because it's exactly what I could expect, but I don't know how to make all folders other than public inaccessible and I would like to run my project after www.mydomain.com/projects/myproject...
What should I do to achieve this goal?

Greetings!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753459/zend-framework-deployment-in-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to put htaccess files in the root, projects and myproject directories to disallow access. I don't know it by hand but it should be

```
deny all
```

Then in your apache config, might be a file named sites-enabled, there you should only need to add the directory config to the default host, e.g.:

```
<virtualhost foobar:80>
    some crap here
    some more crap
    <Directory /projects/myproject/public>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</virtualhost>
```

That should make your site work.

Remember to add the following to your project's htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /projects/myproject
```

Hope that helps.