# Can I put the public folder files to the site root Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am on shared hosting server and I am going to place `zend` there but I can not touch `httpd.conf` file to make a virtual host as it is shared hosting and they do not allow me.

If I keep `index.php` file and `.htaccess` in the `public` folder I have to make a virtual host to hide the `public` from the `url`.

So, I though that I can put the `public` folder files (`index.php, .htaccess`) in the site root thus I don't need to create a virtual server for this and my site is accessible without the need of `public` in `url`.

Is there anything make my site unsafe if I put `index.php` file out of `public` folder.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753459/zend-framework-deployment-in-server/3765443#3765443.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to these files can cause some security risks. An option could be to place a .htaccess file within each of the application and libray folders to prevent access.

e.g

```
<Files *>
Deny from all
</Files>
```