# Hosting a zend framework project on a shared host

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need help in hosting my zendframework project.When i host it i can only view the home page but i cannot navigate to other pages. I think it is something to do with the .htaccess file.
my directory structure looks like this:

```
.public-html
.htaccess
.myproject
  .applicaton
  .public 
  .library 
  .tests
```

i will be very graetful for any assistance.

Comment: What error messages are being displayed and/or logged to your error log?  What does your .htaccess file look like?  Are you installing Zend yourself or is it provided by the host?  Without more information this question can't be answered.

Comment: There are many approaches to ZF on shared hosting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753459/zend-framework-deployment-in-server/3765443#3765443

Answer (score 2):

Based on the directory structure you posted, it looks like your .htaccess is in the wrong place.  Move it into the public folder and try again. (Your .htaccess file should be in the same folder as your index.php file, per the [Recommended Project Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html).)

Comment: Also I believe your hosting will only serve the files under `public-html` folder. So after moving the `.htaccess` to the `public` folder as @Jeremy mentioned, I think you should smylink (assuming this is a linux box) `public-html` to `public` folder.