# how to run zend framework on remote server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working on **zend Framework**, I already create a website using zend Framework but now I want to run my Project on remote server. But, when i transfer my all Project data to remote server it not works.

my zend framework projects good on **localhost**.

I also read the manual of `Getting Started with Zend Framework By Rob Allen, www.akrabat.com.`

So, after reading this manual I found this important article.

```
You must also ensure that Apache is configured to support .htaccess files. This is usually done by
changing the setting:
! AllowOverride None
to
! AllowOverride All
in your httpd.conf file. Check with your distribution’s documentation for exact details. You will not be able
to navigate to any page other than the home page in this tutorial if you have not configured mod_rewrite
and .htaccess usage correctly.
```

But actually I am using **sharing remote server** so from where I change`apache config` and also `mod_rewrite`.

Note :- my project works on localhost as i have make some changes after reading this documentation.

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV display nothing same thing happen with my localhost also but when i make changes after that i am able to see the project

Comment: You can check if your host supports .htaccess by creating a folder and set a .htaccess in it and write some text in it like "JUST TO TEST IF HTACCESS IS SUPPORTED", save it, and open the browser to that folder, if you get 500 Internal Server Error, then your host DOES support .htaccess ...

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV Yes i got 500 Internal Server Error, so what i can do ?

Comment: Well, it's strange, btw i also encounterd a problem like that, and i couldn't install anythinng/modify on the server, so what i did is downloading the Zend library and everytime i needed to call a class i just wrote the whole path to that class instead of just begining with "Zend/..."

Comment: On shared hosting, you often have no control of the the virtual hosting mapping which would typically make your `public` folder the web root. In that case, you have to either modify the top-level `.htaccess` to push your requests down into the `public` folder or tweak your folder locations and the bootstrap file to point to your new locations. For a list of several approaches, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3765443/131824

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling there's an error that's not being displayed. Are you sure you are displaying all of your errors?

1. Add the following to your `index.php`:

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
   ```
2. Have you set these in your config file (most likely the `[development : production]` section of your `application.ini`)?

   ```
   [development : production]
   phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
   phpSettings.display_errors = 1
   resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
   ```
3. Is your application in the `development` environment? You can most likely set this in your `index.php` like so:

   ```
   // Define application environment
   defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
       || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));
   ```

This might show errors that are being hidden from you. I hope the error can help you solve your problem.