# Running a Zend Framework Project on a shared server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, xampp

I'm trying to upload my ZF Project to shared hosting

On my XAMPP, ZF's index page is located (and I access my page) at `http://localhost/ZFprojectname/public`

On the shared hosting in the root directory I have installed Joomla.

I want to access my ZF in the manner of `http://mywebsite.com/booking/`

so in this case, when going to `http://mywebsite.com/booking/` I should be accessing ZF's public folder (as far as I understand).

And, I'd like to put my ZFproject in `public_html/somefolderName/`

How would you do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [zend framework deployment in server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753459/zend-framework-deployment-in-server)

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting do not support defining Document Root path so you can use `.htaccess` to forward the request to `public` folder instead.

Create a `.htaccess` file inside the `booking` directory with the following rule.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Mikey, Your question does not mentions anything about Joomla. Please post another question.

Comment: In my question I wrote that in the root directory I have Joomla, and I want to put ZF inside the booking folder. When I wrote the HTACCESS file, joomla didn't pay attention to it and loaded the front page

Comment: I found another way to do it, but it's not very clean, so I'd like to accomplish the way you suggest

Comment: @Mikey, Ok sorry about that, Joomla has its own `.htaccess` so it may be interfering with this rule. Please post that rule.