# php - Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I wanna match an url like this `http://localhost/sunnetwap/1-hot` and rewrite into this
`http://localhost/sunnetwap/?c=1&s=hot`.
In my Bootstrap and and _initRoutes function i wrote:

```
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                "([0-9]*)-([a-z]*)", 
                array(
                    'module' => 'default',
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'index'
                ),
                array(
                    1 => 'c',
                    2 => 's'
                ));
        $frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('home',$route);
```

but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Your route will match zero or more numbers, followed by a dash, followed by zero or more letters. That does not in any way match the example path you gave: `/sunnetwap/?c=1&s=hot`

Comment: @TimFountain: Sorry, my mistake, i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to the base url of your app.

It is possible that you have deployed your app at the base url `http://localhost/`. In this case, your routes would need to include the `sunnetwap` portion.

But I'm guessing that your app is deployed to `http://localhost/sunnetwap/`. In that case, your route is fine, but it's likely that you either have a `sunnetwap` alias on `localhost` or  that the whole app is dropped into into your `<docroot>/sunnetapp` and that you have moved contents of the `public` folder up a level with corresponding changes to `.htaccess`. Both of these will potentially have impact on the routing.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3765443/131824) for some ideas on how to deploy to a sub-directory when you can't map a virtual host to your app.

Comment: i use .htaccess in my sunnetwap folder.

Comment: What's the content of the .htaccess? The problem is that even though your `.htaccess` routes the Apache request through `index.php`, ZF still sees the incoming url as `sunnetwap/1-hot`. Of course, with the `sunnetwap` prefix, none of your routes match. The solution is include `sunnetwap` in your routes or to see the other approaches to handling deployment below the web root.