# Running a Zend Framework App on a shared hosting that is also a subdomain

Tags: php, zend-framework, shared-hosting, subdomain

I build a Zend Framework application with help of the Zend tool and had it running on my own XAMPP installation and a home XAMPP server (both windows). Now I'm moving it to a linux shared hosting environment. I've tried [this method](http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/) and some of the methods that he links to, changing the .htaccess and/or links in the index.php. But I keep getting 500 erros. Pages that require a login do foward me to the login form, but that also gives a 500 error.

I don't get why this is happening, but a guess is that the shared hosting server act as a subdomain of another URL. Could this be a problem or should I look in at some other factors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your `public/` folder the document root on the subdomain?

Comment: No I'm not allow to do that, so i tried putting the application folder etc in de public folder en get there trough chaning the .htacces and index.php. That didn't work (same behaviour). I also tried putting the public folder as a seperate folder in there as well and redrirecting there trough .htaccess like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115547/zend-framework-on-shared-hosting). But i keeps giving 500 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heinze,

can you provide any log information from the host at all?

Matt

Comment: yes, didn't think about looking at that. Seems a plugin is causing troubles!


PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'LoggedInAs' was not found in the registry; used paths:\nZend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/vhosts/analytics.greenorange.com/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/' in /var/www/vhosts/analytics.greenorange.com/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader

Comment: This was the problem

Thanks a ton!

Comment: No worries mate. Personally, I always have the PHP and zf app log files being tailed in a terminal/shell window (I use a Mac now after years of Linux - but still haven't come around to Console yet). 

I hope it helps, check out a post I wrote for tips and pointers on debugging PHP apps: http://bit.ly/kDQfe8