# how to configure resources.frontController.baseUrl with www.nomsite.com?

Tags: php, zend-framework

i need to configure out the resources.frontController.baseUrl  with www.nomsite.com in zend framework.
i'm working with version 1.11 and i did this in the application.ini:

resources.frontController.baseUrl = "http://nomsite.com"

this works fine , but if i access to the website with the www.nomsite.com i get "404. That’s an error.The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

plz how to add the "www" ??
plz i need help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are getting the web server (Apache, nginx, etc) "404 Not Found" message rather than the ZF *in-appplication* message. That means that the request is never getting to your app, which means the issue exists higher up in the stack, at the web-server level.

Typically this is because the web-server has mapped requests for that domain to some path, but your ZF app needs that path to be the path for your application's `./public/` directory.

If you have control of the web-server mapping, then change it point to your app's `./public/` directory. If not - as is the case in most shared hosting environments - then move your application and/or rename the `./public/'` directory to match the web-server's expectations.

In the case of shared hosting, there are usually some other [mapping tweaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115685/131824) you need to make.

Comment: thanks for reply , i'm trying to understand but i can't , i have configure it out to access to th website without the name public but i can't figure out or even find a tutorial to understand and get how can i make it work with the www...

Comment: On Apache, sounds like you need [ServerAilas](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias)