# Set .htaccess for Zend Framework 1 on web server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

this is my first time I try to put some project on web server. I really don't know how to set the .htaccess file of my Zend Framework project.

I have this structure:

```
/webroot
    /ZendProject
        /application
        /docs
        /library
        /public
            /css
            /images
            /js
            .htaccess 
            index.php 
        /tests
    /include
```

this is my default .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What is the problem ? What are you trying to do ? What is the question ?

Comment: I need to send any request to index.php in public folder

Comment: So what are you having trouble with? Your current `.htaccess` should do the job.

Comment: If i try `www.webhost.it` it don't redirect on index.php, but i get error 403

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115547/zend-framework-on-shared-hosting

Answer (score 1):

Your public directory .htaccess should be something like this

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} cron.php
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !rewrite_module>
    DirectoryIndex alert.php
</IfModule>
```

If you host your project somewhere where you don't have control over Apache, add this .htaccess file to your project root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
php_value magic_quotes 0
php_flag magic_quotes off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```